# Cannot store user in Mongodb Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't store a user in database, I am using Mongooose.
in app.js:

```
var new_user = new User({
username:'timtime',
password:'time'
})
new_user.save();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Users');
```

So when i run the app, it should store timtime in database. In my database I have a db named Users. In Users I have a collection called Login. That is it. When I type db.Login.find(), it returns nothing.

this is my database:

```
>show dbs
Users 0.08GB
local 0.07GB
>use Users
>show collections
Login
System.indexes
>db.Login.find()
>
```

I used db.createCollections to create "Login" collections.

```
>db.createCollections("Login")
```

In user.js I have:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
username:{type: String, required: true},
password:{type: String, required: true}
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;

// generate a salt
bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
if (err) return next(err);

// hash the password using our new salt
bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt)
});
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Login', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Does `db.logins.find()` show your docs?

Comment: sorry I am new to mongo. What do you mean docs?

Comment: The user documents you tried to save.

Comment: No it doesn't, db.logins.find() doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the callback to save()?  It might help you debug too.

```
new_user.save(function(err, user) { 
  if(err)
    console.log('error saving: ' + err);

  if(user)
    console.log('saved user');

});
```

Edit: Also, are you sure you have a mongodb connection?  Try putting the mongoose.connect statement before you save a user.

Comment: Hey, I am not getting any errors. I made some changes to my questions, I added more details about my database. Hope this helps in figuring out the problem

Comment: Try adding `mongoose.set('debug', true);` and make sure mongoose is using the right collection when saving, there should be a message come up in the console/terminal.  I've had it happen where mongoose was using a pluralized collection name instead of a singular name( Logins vs Login).  If that is the case you can force the collection name in the schema.  `var UserSchema = new Schema({
username:{type: String, required: true},
password:{type: String, required: true}
}, {collection: 'Login'});`

Comment: I figured out the problem.
Solution: in user.js the last line:
module.exports = mongoose.model('Login', UserSchema);
should be 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);

I think this is because my database is also called 'Users'